# Catch sort event on custom material table component (Angular 6)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

Based on days of research and combination of multiple sources and help from others I built this custom table component that I could use for all my tables that has all the basics built in already.
All I need to do to create a table is define columns and pass in the data.

But now I want to add option to remember sorting per user with cookies and I can do it if catch the sort event on the page where I use the custom table component but that defeats the purpose of the custom component and it would be so much cleaner if I could just catch it inside the custom component.

Example table creation with custom comp:

```
<dyn-table [data]="users" [displayedColumns]="displayedColumns" matSort (matSortChange)="sortChange($event)">
    <dyn-col name="user_id"></dyn-col>
    <dyn-col name="user_name"></dyn-col>
</dyn-table>
```

I need a way to create a table without adding `(matSortChange)="sortChange($event)"` here but instead catching sortChange inside my custom table component.

StackBlitz with the custom table component catching the event in app.component.ts(should catch in dyn-table.component.ts).
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jw9whh

Seems like it should be a simple case but I have not found a solution to this yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you manipulate `matSort` directive on your custom component then you can just use `HostListener` decorator to catch that event:

**dyn-table.component.ts**

```
@HostListener('matSortChange', ['$event'])
sortChange(e) {
  // save cookie with table sort data here
  console.log(e);
}
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bo8ojy?file=src/app/app.component.html)**